# R database extracting limit issue

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

i am a beginner to R and i dont know whether my title is appropriate to the problem  , i have a problem with extracting some data from sql in R  , this is the code

```
> flights = select(paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 1000))

> flights = select(paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 10000))

> flights = select(paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 100000))
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1e+05' at line 1
Called from: eval(substitute(browser(skipCalls = pos), list(pos = 9 - frame)), 
envir = sys.frame(frame))

> flights = select(paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 1000000))
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1e+06' at line 1
Called from: eval(substitute(browser(skipCalls = pos), list(pos = 9 - frame)), 
envir = sys.frame(frame))

> flights = select(paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 1000001))

> flights = select(paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 100000001))
```

so here is my doubt when limit less than 10000 or up to 4 zeros there is no error but about 5 or more zeros throw the error .But if the limit ends with number other than 0 then there is no error why ?

Also the select function

```
select <- function (query, connection=con) {
return(as.data.frame(dbGetQuery(connection, query)))
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big numbers are converted to the scientific notation, you can run `options(scipen=999)` to prevent this:

```
options(scipen=999)
paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 1000000)
# "SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000000"
```

To restore it, run `options(scipen=0)`:

```
options(scipen=0)
paste("SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT", 1000000)
#"SELECT DISTINCT flight FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1e+06"
```